# Ubuntu freezes at login

Tags: windows, login

I recently installed another OS in my laptop to have two OS, I installed Windows 8.1.  When i choose Ubuntu it freezes at log in screen.  What can i do to fix this?

Ubuntu is my main O.S.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What ubuntu version are u using?

Answer (score 1):

We need some more information. I assume you're saying you installed 8.1 after Ubuntu? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

If you have another computer available, try hitting "e" while Ubuntu is highlighted in your GRUB screen. Highlight the kernel line (it'll be obvious, something along the lines of

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff
```

don't worry) and hit "e" again to edit it. Scroll to the end and type 1, then hit [Enter]. Boot as usual into Ubuntu.

You're now in single-user mode, as root. Be **very** careful here. Run the following command:

```
fsck -p
```

Once that's done, type

```
reboot
```

and your computer will reboot. Hopefully Ubuntu will let you login now. If not, we need more information about your installation.

If you can't even make it into single-user mode, your installation is probably hosed and you need to reinstall. Use your Windows partition to rescue as much as you can/want to.

Comment: Sorry, the last comment had some error.  I installed Windows 8.1 to use unity 3D and later put Ubuntu since the partition creator is a lot easier.